Provide a limited view of the data in SQL Server
I have an application that is multi-tenant. So a single database has data for all the organizations that use it.
Is there a way to provide access to the database, so my customers can connect to it with any analytics tool such as Power BI.
There is the Org table - where I can specify the PK of that table they can get.
Then there's the Event table where it has a FK to the Org table.
And then a signup (to the event) table that has a FK to the event and a FK to the user.
And the most difficult one is the user table. If the user is signed up for an event then that customer can get that user. Which means multiple customers can see that user table row.
This is specifically SQL Server. So I would need to craft some view that determines which user records a given user can view. While I could duplicate the Ord PK in the Event table, the user record, as multiple customers can get it - won't work with an added FK.
Is there a way to do this?

You should provide the CREATE scripts of your tables and some sample data so it's easier to conceptualize your database structure. Also, from a security perspective, it's usually better practice to implement a separate database per tenant.
But putting all of that aside, your use case fits the model for the Row-Level Security feature in SQL Server:

Row-level security (RLS) enables you to use group membership or execution context to control access to rows in a database table.
Row-level security simplifies the design and coding of security in your application. RLS helps you implement restrictions on data row access. For example, you can ensure that workers access only those data rows that are pertinent to their department. Another example is to restrict customers' data access to only the data relevant to their company.
The access restriction logic is located in the database tier rather than away from the data in another application tier. The database system applies the access restrictions every time that data access is attempted from any tier. This makes your security system more reliable and robust by reducing the surface area of your security system.

With Row-Level Security, you can create a table valued function to apply the filter logic based on the Org table (most likely) and then create a security policy to apply that function  against all of your tables. This abstracts away the security logic so you don't have to implement it manually with every object (e.g. wrapped in a view for each object) and refractors the code to one place.
Row-Level Security can also be used to define policies that block which data manipulation queries can be ran by which users against specific tables.
Row-Level Security is not a substitute for best practices around security otherwise. It just adds an additional layer of protection that provides automatic data filtering logic based on whatever relevant criteria you define based on your end users.

Thank you. And I can't do a database per tenant because the users sign up for events under multiple organizations. So they are shared. But an organization can only see the users that signed up for their events.

Perhaps just create Views that have where clauses in them:
Select * from someTable where Org.Name = 'Some Client'

Then Power BI only needs access to the views it should have access to.
Could be a simple idea for a complex problem.

That turns out to be a very complex solution. I have 12+ tables that are restricted. And I have 183 (and growing) distinct users who may use this. So that's 12x183 views (and growing).
